# Problem Specifying Source Directory to GHC

Tags: haskell, ghc

This is an embarrassingly simple problem, but its solution yet eludes me. As the title indicates, I simply want to specify to GHC the location of all my source files. This should be simple; the [GHC user guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.2/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html#search-path):

> -i*dirs*
>
> This flag appends a colon-separated
>   list of dirs to the search path.

So, I tried the following invocations:

```
ghc -isrc/ -v -outputdir build/ --make -Wall Main.hs
ghc -isrc/: -v -outputdir build/ --make -Wall Main.hs
ghc -i:src/: -v -outputdir build/ --make -Wall Main.hs
ghc -i"src/" -v -outputdir build/ --make -Wall Main.hs
ghc -i"src/": -v -outputdir build/ --make -Wall Main.hs
ghc -i:"src/": -v -outputdir build/ --make -Wall Main.hs
```

On every invocation GHC gave the error: "<no location info>: can't find file: Main.hs"

As you probably could have guessed, Main.hs is located in a subdirectory from the working directory called "src". Just in case it matters, I'm on Windows XP, and I'm using GHC 6.12.2. I'm assuming there is some small problem that I'm just missing.

Comment: Have you tried with a space between -i and the path? "ghc -i src/ -v -outputdir build/ --make -Wall Main.hs"

Comment: I have; it causes GHC to completely misinterpret what you mean.

Comment: Alright, that's good to know. Wasn't sure of so I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`-i` specifies where GHC will search for *other* source files, other than the ones you specify on the command line. So your `Main.hs` there will also need a src/ prefix. E.g.

```
$ ghc -isrc src/Main.hs --make 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( src/Main.hs, src/Main.o )
Linking src/Main ...
```

Alternatively, you could use cabal, and have `cabal init` generate all the build metadata for you.

Comment: Ah! That did indeed work. Thanks for correcting my misunderstanding!