# Specifying the search path for "load" operations in ghci

Tags: haskell, ghci

In [Loading source files](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/loading-source-files.html) it states that the search path for finding source files is specified with the -i option :

```
ghci -idir1:...:dirn
```

Does this mean that when one performs :

```
:load test.hs
```

then ghci looks in the directories above for test.hs? I saw the response at 
[Problem Specifying Source Directory to GHC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5760396) but I am still not clear about this.

For example in Windows XP I put test.hs in :

```
C:\Documents and Settings\winuser\My Documents
```

and then ran :

```
ghci -iC:\Documents and Settings\winuser\My Documents
```

However upon doing `:load test.hs`, ghci complained about not being able to find the file.

[EDIT 1]

I want to avoid using `:cd` because it unloads all loaded modules, which prevents me from loading files from multiple locations

[EDIT 2 : response to jozefg]

```
--C:\A\A.hs
module A where
myaddA::Int->Int->Int
myaddA x y = x+y

--C:\B\B.hs
module B where
myaddB::Int->Int->Int
myaddB x y = x+y
```

Then I can do the following :

```
Prelude> :cd C:\A
Prelude> :load A
[1 of 1] Compiling A                ( A.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: A.
*A> myaddA 2 3
5
*A> :cd C:\B
Warning: changing directory causes all loaded modules to be unloaded,
because the search path has changed.
Prelude> :load B
[1 of 1] Compiling B                ( B.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: B.
*B> myaddB 3 4
7
```

However I haven't found a way to make modules A and B simultaneously available when the modules are stored in files in different locations

[EDIT 3 : response to jozefg]

```
>ls
temp  temp2
>more temp/A.hs
module A where
addA = (+)
>more temp2/B.hs
module B where
addB = (+)
>cd temp
>ghci -i../temp2
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> import A B

<interactive>:1:10: parse error on input `B'
```

[EDIT 4 : response to jozefg]

```
>ls
temp  temp2
>more temp/A.hs
module A where
addA = (+)
>more temp2/B.hs
module B where
addB = (+)
>cd temp
>ghci -i../temp2
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> import A

<no location info>:
    Could not find module `A'
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
Prelude> import B

<no location info>:
    Could not find module `B'
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
```

Comment: How did that even parse? You have spaces and `:`'s in your directory path

Comment: @jozefg I'm attempting it just one directory level up from the source I'm trying to load and I can't get it to work.  It seems this problem exists even with a valid path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The load path is how GHCi searches for modules. So if you named your module `Test.hs` and added

```
 module Test where
```

Than you can do

```
 > :load Test
```

otherwise you can use

```
 > :cd SomeDirectory
 > :load test.hs
```

---

Response to edit:

(Warning, I run eshell so the commands/paths look different)

```
~         $ mkdir temp
~         $ mkdir temp/temp temp/temp2
temp      $ find-file temp/A.hs
-- In A.hs
module A where
addA = (+)
--
temp      $ find-file temp2/B.hs
-- In B.hs
module B where
addB = (+)
--
temp      $ cd temp
temp/temp $ ghci -i../temp2
> :load A B
> import B
```

And now I have access to both `A` and `B`.

Comment: Thanks I am aware of `:cd` but I wanted to avoid using this because it unloads modules, which prevents me from loading files from different locations. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: @artella Is there any reason to avoid using Haskell's module system? That's what's supposed to handle these things

Comment: I tried your suggestion (see edit above), but couldn't get it to work as I wanted.

Comment: @artella What's your load path? It works fine for me

Comment: But in my example where I had modules A and modules B, were you able to simultaneously use `myaddA` (from module A) and `myaddB` (from module B)? I found that at any given time I could either use one or the other, but not both (because the modules are in files at different locations)? The example you specified works fine for me.

Comment: @artella Try `import` instead of `:load`. Eg `> import A`

Comment: Tried `import` but it doesn't work either. So when I do `:cd C:\A` then I can do `import A` (but only after I have done `:load A`), but as soon as I do `:cd C:\B` then I can no longer do `import A`.

Comment: @artella Notice I'm not using `:cd` which appears to mess with the load path

Comment: Just tried your suggestion in linux, but couldn't get it to work (see [EDIT 3 : response to jozefg])

Comment: @artella Sorry that was my fault, fixed

Comment: Hmmm I still cannot get it to work. See [EDIT 4 : response to jozefg] for the latest attempt.

Comment: @artella Try the same setup but in GHCi, `:load A B <enter> import B`

Answer (score 4):

In the context of running `ghci` with `stack`.

Step 1:

```
 stack ghci --ghci-options -i"C:\Documents and Settings\winuser\My Documents"
```

Step 2: (inside ghci)

```
:show paths
```

module import search paths: `c:\Documents`

It seems ghci doesn't like "space" in the path

Step 3: (still inside ghci)

```
:set -iC:\Users\zheh\Desktop\code\Craft3e-0.1.0.10
```

Step 4: (still inside ghci)

```
:show paths
```

So avoid "space" inside path. Search paths can be set with command line options at the beginning or inside ghci, and be checked with `:show paths`