# Why does ghci not use relative paths?

Tags: haskell, ghci, ghc-mod

If I have a project structured like this:

```
project/
  src/
    Foo.hs
    Bar.hs
```

With files Foo.hs:

```
module Foo where  

foo :: String
foo = "foo"
```

and Bar.hs:

```
module Bar where

import Foo 

bar :: String
bar = foo ++ "bar"
```

If my current directory is `src`, and I enter ghci and run `:l Bar.hs`, I get the expected output:

```
[1 of 2] Compiling Foo              ( Foo.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 2] Compiling Bar              ( Bar.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Bar, Foo.
```

But if I move up to the `project` directory (which is where I'd prefer to stay and run vim/ghci/whatever), and try `:l src/Bar.hs`, I get:

```
src/Bar.hs:3:8:
    Could not find module ‘Foo’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Why does ghc not search for Foo in the same directory as Bar? Can I make it do so? And can I propagate that change up to ghc-mod and then to ghcmod.vim? Because I get errors about can't find module when I'm running my syntax checker or ghc-mod type checker in vim.

I'm running ghc 7.10.1.

Comment: In GHCi, `:cd` can change the current working directory - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078059/specifying-the-search-path-for-load-operations-in-ghci .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flag you're looking for is `-i<dir>`:

```
% ghci --help
Usage:

    ghci [command-line-options-and-input-files]

...

In addition, ghci accepts most of the command-line options that plain
GHC does.  Some of the options that are commonly used are:

    -i<dir>         Search for imported modules in the directory <dir>.
```

For example

```
% ls src
Bar.hs Foo.hs
% ghci -isrc
GHCi, version 7.8.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
λ :l Foo
[1 of 1] Compiling Foo              ( src/Foo.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Foo.
λ :l Bar
[1 of 2] Compiling Foo              ( src/Foo.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 2] Compiling Bar              ( src/Bar.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Foo, Bar.
```

You can also [pass `ghc-mod` the `-i<dir>` flag from within `ghcmod.vim`](https://github.com/eagletmt/ghcmod-vim#details)

> If you'd like to give GHC options, set `g:ghcmod_ghc_options`.
>
> ```
> let g:ghcmod_ghc_options = ['-idir1', '-idir2']
> ```
>
> Also, there's buffer-local version `b:ghcmod_ghc_options`.
>
> ```
> autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile ~/.xmonad/* call s:add_xmonad_path()
> function! s:add_xmonad_path()
>   if !exists('b:ghcmod_ghc_options')
>     let b:ghcmod_ghc_options = []
>   endif
>   call add(b:ghcmod_ghc_options, '-i' . expand('~/.xmonad/lib'))
> endfunction
> ```